# when sending a verify email request from keycloak via sendgrid, the resulting url is wrongly encoded

Tags: sendgrid, keycloak

I have a keycloak (4.4.0-Final) installation.
Scenario:

- sendgrid is configured as mail agent (and test mail sending is ok)
- I create a new user in keycloak admin console and I pass it the action "verify email"
- I get an email with a link to verify my email address, but when I click the link, I get the error "We're sorry...
  An error occurred, please login again through your application."
- I now have a closer look at the URL and I see 2 times `&#61;` => http://keycloakurl/.....login-actions/action-token?key=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUx...&client_id=client-...
- When I change `&#61;` to = , the url works.

Does someone know if this is a bug in sendgrid, or a bug in the keycloak templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not keycloak, but sendgrid (ref: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-8536). We fixed the issue by dropping sendgrid and going to mailjet.

Comment: It is indeed an issue in the Keycloak, because it uses HTML escape sequences inside the URL. Issue does not happen in Gmail, because it would parse such sequences, when rendering an email and therefore hide an issue from you. Here is a bug report: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-8499

Comment: You could argue that the problem lies with sendgrid, who should be able to parse escape sequences properly.  protection.outlook.com seems to handle it OK.

Answer (score 3):

I know you have moved ahead with Mailjet but I would like to share my solution here as it may help others. I noticed this issue only happens if Email Tracking is enabled at SendGrid side. Try after disabling all tracking configurations under Setting -> Tracking screen.